# UIImageView not responding to gestures on certain edges

Tags: ios

I am making a custom control which consists of UIImageView and Label. The control behaves like a checkbox.

Here is the code:

```
-(instancetype) initWithTitle:(NSString *)title normalCheckBoxImage:(NSString *)normalCheckBoxImage selectedCheckBoxImage:(NSString *)selectedCheckBoxImage
{
    self = [super init];

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    self.normalCheckBoxImageName = normalCheckBoxImage;
    self.selectedCheckBoxImageName = selectedCheckBoxImage;
    self.title = title;

    [self setupSubViews];

    [self registerGestureRecognizers];

    return self;
}

-(void) registerGestureRecognizers
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxTapped:)];
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [self.checkBoxImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void) checkBoxTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    self.isChecked = !self.isChecked;

    if(self.isChecked)
    {
        [self.checkBoxImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.selectedCheckBoxImageName]];
    }

    else
    {
        [self.checkBoxImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.normalCheckBoxImageName]];
    }

}

-(void) setupSubViews
{
    self.checkBoxImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.normalCheckBoxImageName]];

    self.checkBoxImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);

    NSLog(@"width = %f; height = %f",self.checkBoxImageView.frame.size.width,self.checkBoxImageView.frame.size.height);

    [self.checkBoxImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    // The init with frame should be replaced by the NSConstraints
    self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.checkBoxImageView.frame.size.width + 5, 10, 100, 20)];

    self.titleLabel.text = self.title;

    [self addSubview:self.checkBoxImageView];
    [self addSubview:self.titleLabel];
}
```

I have attached gesture recognizer to the UIImageView. But for some reason it only fires when I am close to the left edge of the UIImageView. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If I touch in the middle of the uIImageView then it does not do anything.

Here is the image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no option for color overlay layers. Xcode 5 with iOS 7

Comment: I am running on the simulator. There is no option for color overlay layers. Please check before assuming things and making people run on a wild goose chase. Check out my updated question.

Comment: Wait for a minute let me give you image may be wrong menu name not on mac

Comment: I fixed the problem! It was the frame of the super view which was not set correctly. Fixed.

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-simulator/     tip 3 buddy and apologies for sending you on wild goose chase :|

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the frame for the super view was not correct. Instead of width and height of 50 X 50 it was 50 X 20.

```
AZCheckBox *checkbox = [[AZCheckBox alloc] initWithTitle:@"I agree" normalCheckBoxImage:@"NormalCheckBoxImage" selectedCheckBoxImage:@"SelectedCheckBoxImage"];
    checkbox.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 50);

    checkbox.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:checkbox];
```